# BDD how to isolate a test that depends on data

Tags: bdd, specflow

I'd be honest, I am completely new to this.

Say I have the following scenario:

```
Scenario: User grid displays information about all users
Given the application have at least one user
When I go to the user grid page
Then I should see a list of user data in the user grid
```

How could I ensure to keep the test isolated for this scenario while I know the application contains no user data at the start of the test?

I can see the following options so far:

1. Add a create user scenario before firing this scenario. (This breaks isolation.)
2. Have code to check on `have at least one user`, and inserts if it doesn't. (Never seen this done on the internet yet, is this normal or good practice?)

Answer (score 0):

I think your test is too abstract. Try being a little more concrete. If you were to use:

```
Given I add a user called bob
When I view the users grid page
Then I should see bob in the user list
```

then I think it is now much more obvious that you need to use something like your option 2. You might even consider

```
Given I add a user called bob
And I add a user called bill
....
```

or if you prefer

```
Given I add an accounts team
...
```

Don't forget SpecFlow bindings are just methods so behind the scenes you can

```
[Given ("I add an accounts team")]
public void GivenIAddAnAccountsTeam()
{
  GivenIAddAUserCalled("bob");
  GivenIAddAUserCalled("bill");
}
```

Don't forget BDD is all about giving examples. Those examples should have everything you need to describe that you need to test your scenario, so don't make then too weak. Also you will find that it makes it much easier to write those scenarios, if you make your objects known instances, such as bob, who isn't an admin but has permissions to see the accounts data. This way when you are discussing your scenarios everybody already knows how bob should appear on the user list.

Comment: Thanks. Is this a common thing to do and "good practice"? It just seems odd to me that the test have to perform a bit of housekeeping (`clear all users`, `add a user called bob`).

Comment: You are right, normally you wouldn't want to clear the users as you'll start each scenario fresh. However sometimes you might want a more composite approach, `Given a user bob` followed by `Given\And a user bill` to build up your scenario, and this is what I was more trying to illustrate.

Comment: Sounds great. Should I put the checks for Bob in the `Background:`? I just recently discovered that SpecFlow supports `Background`. Or is this for something else?

Comment: I treat the scenarios like a Red Green Refactor cycle as well. So initially add a new `Scenario` that is as simple as possible(!!), then add your `[binding]`s to get it working, and finally refactor it into `Background`s if there is an advantage to doing that.

Comment: Also, you might treat bob and bill as just concepts, you don't need to explicitly code down their responsibilities and attributes. The point is that you and your team, know what "bob" represents so that you have no doubt when you are devising your scenario.